# Table is read only although primary key is present

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, toad

I'm not able to update values on tables present on my database using MySQL Workbench (or equivalent software such as Toad Edge):

The tables are read-only although primary key is present.

Only very few times the "read only" label is not present and MySQL Workbench lets me update table fields values, but if this occurs, as soon as I run another query (or if I run the same query twice), the "read only" label appears again.

[image]

Comment: The problem is not clear at all, please provide some images, or exactly how is your database structure and what types of query creates such problem. I mean, be more specific.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of MySQL Workbench? It sometimes has major bug in releases. Try to view your Management->Client Connections tab in MySQL Workbench and check your connections and queries there. It will show your query state.

Comment: @RakibulIslam I've updated the question by proving an image.

Comment: Please show the `CREATE` statement for that table `bhLogo`.

Comment: @HameesA.Khan Yes I'm using the latest version, I went where you told me and "The account you are currently using does not have sufficient privileges to view the client connections." message is shown. I have to ask the DBA. The strange thing is that sometimes MySQL Workbench lets me edit that data...very strange

Comment: Are you trying to edit data by double clicking cells of the result and then typing new values in it? If yes,I would recommend you to disconnect from server and then reconnect. After that Try to `UPDATE` some rows by typing `UPDATE`statement and check what it gives you? One more thing, Please tell us your DB Engine (InnoDB, MyISAM,...). Because, few engines only provide table-level locking (not row-level locking), which means that one user's query will lock whole table for him.

Answer (score 0):

This is all depends of the kind of query that you execute. If it's a simple one table query with simple WHERE command, then it should not be marked as "Read Only". However if the query contains an aggregation, group by or joins, then it will be marked as read only as trying to update the showed rows should be considered ambiguous.

At least Workbench allows editing on simple WHERE filters by default. Other IDEs, like SQLYog, marks any manually queried results as Read Only. However it could be overridden and it does an evaluation if it's safe to direct edit the data, if not, it stays as Read Only.

If this is not case, then it could be that the user that you are using to connect  do not have UPDATE or INSERT rights.